# Cron expression to schedule a task

Tags: java, salesforce, scheduler, cronexpression

I want to schedule a task from Jan 14th to July 12th every weekdays at 09.00 PM.
Can someone help me in writing this cron expression.

Thanks,

Naveen.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add three entries in the crontab file for this scenario

```
00 21 14-31 1 1-5 /your/command/to/execute
00 21 * 2-6 1-5 /your/command/to/execute
00 21 1-12 7 1-5 /your/command/to/execute
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Isn't it possible with single cron expression?.If I use 3 cron expression I need to schedule 3 jobs and this is a overhead and a problem . Please advice me how I do this with single cron expression.

Comment: Hi Naveen, for the condition you provided it cannot be written in a single cron expression. Secondly, cron is highly optimized and very lightweight process, the only thing it does is trigger your script(if required), so overhead because of multiple cron expression should not be an issue. If a script is executed then overhead to server totally depends on the script complexity, it has nothing to do with cron daemon.

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer :

```
0 0 21 1-14 1 MON-FRI 2015
0 0 21 ? 2-6 MON-FRI 2015
0 0 21 1-12 7 MON-FRI 2015
```

**21 :** fires at 9 pm

**? :** any day of the month

**1-7 :** January to July

**MON-FRI :** Weekdays

I don't think you can do it from January 12th to July 14th.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Isn't it possible with single cron expression?.If I use 3 cron expression I need to schedule 3 jobs and this is a overhead and a problem . Please advice me how I do this with single cron expression.

Comment: `0 0 21 ? 1-7 MON-FRI 2015` will give you that, but then you cannot achieve the 12th January to 14th July. This will be directly from January 1st to July 31st.